# Some css statements from linked file are working others are not

Tags: css, django-templates, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'core/css/index.css' %}">

    <title>OBs Lawn Care</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <!-- background image-->
    <img src="{% static "core/images/lawn.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>

    <!-- navigation bar-->
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="nav_logo" href="#">LOGO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav_item">fff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav_item">Services</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h1>COMPANY NAME</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

and index.css:

```
img{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    z-index:-2;
}

#nav{
    z-index:-1;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 7%;
}

#nav li{
    display:inline;
}

#nav a{
    color:black;
}
h1{
color:blue;
}
```

all of the `img` styling works fine but the `h1` and `#nav a`  color will not change from its default. (Note I tried styling directly in the html with `<h1 style="color: blue">COMPANY NAME</h1>` and this worked, so I believe it has to be something with the css file) Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax was just a little off, close tho! :) this should work, heres the example of it on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bD9nC/32/

```
#nav{
    z-index:-1;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 7%;
}

ul#nav{
    display:inline;
}

a#nav{
    color:black;
}
```